# How to call RESTful from another server by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I have a server A running a web application (in ASP.NET MVC 4), using JavaScript to call a REST API residing on server B.

JavaScript in Server A:

```
$.ajax({            
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://serverB/api/Employee/Manpower",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: convertTojsonWithData(REQHEAD(), EMPDETAIL()),
    success: function (Result) {                    
        //alert(data);
        $("#txtOption").val(Result);
        alert($("#txtOption").val());
    }
});
```

When I run my project, I received nothing from the REST API on Server B. And when I changed my `url` to `api/Employee/Manpower`, the API endpoint becomes `http://localhost:1111/api/Employee/Manpower`.

Please guide me!

Answer (score 0):

What is Server B's ip address ?

Try with Ip Address of server B.
for example call http://192.168.5.1:8080/api/Employee/Manpower

Comment: port no is not added . Do check by adding correct port no.

Comment: You can check network calls happening in the browser in the network console.

Comment: at 192.168.115.67 I use port 80